# Ionic v1 Push notification for iOS and Android with passing data

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, push

I have a Ionic v1 app and I have used phonegap-plugin-push before for my app it worked well with Android app.

But now my requirement is to have a push notification for Android as well as for iOS. Adding phonegap-plugin-push crash my ios build. While creating build it gives me error:

> GoogleCloudMessaging.h file not found in PushPlugin.m

I didn't found any relevant solution. Now I'm trying out with new plugin cordova-plugin-fcm but it is giving error as:

> {"multicast_id":5214231492265030304,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

But I didn't found any place to enter sender id.

I am looking for a solution with any of the one plugin or new plugin suggestion which will work with both Android and iOS.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: If you are looking for a library recommendation, this is unfortunately off-topic.

Comment: ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
try this plugin